# display minutes in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube

I am using a code library called YOUMAX that displays youtube videos from my channel on my website.

I am having trouble making the videos show up show the correct time uploaded. Right now, I have it to say that it was upload "3 hour ago" or "2 days ago" or "5 months ago"..

But I cannot figure out the code for minutes.

```
function getDateDiff(timestamp) {
    if (null === timestamp || timestamp === "" || timestamp === "undefined") return "?";
    var splitDate = ((timestamp.toString().split('T'))[0]).split('-');
    var splitTime = ((timestamp.toString().split('T'))[1]).split(':');
    var d1 = new Date();
    var d1Y = d1.getFullYear();
    var d2Y = parseInt(splitDate[0], 10);
    var d1M = d1.getMonth() + 1;
    var d2M = parseInt(splitDate[1], 10);
    var d1D = d1.getDate();
    var d2D = parseInt(splitDate[2], 10);
    var d1H = d1.getHours();
    var d2H = parseInt(splitTime[0], 10);
    var diffInHours = (d1H + 24 * d1D + 720 * d1M + 12 * d1Y) - (d2H + 24 * d2D + 720 * d2M + 12 * d2Y);
    if (diffInHours <= 1) return "1 Hour";
    else if (diffInHours < 23) return diffInHours + " Hours";
    var diffInDays = (d1D + 30 * d1M + 360 * d1Y) - (d2D + 30 * d2M + 360 * d2Y);
    if (diffInDays < 7) return diffInDays + " days";
    else if (diffInDays > 7 && diffInDays < 14) return "1 week";
    else if (diffInDays >= 14 && diffInDays < 30) return Math.floor(diffInDays / 7) + "     weeks";
    var diffInMonths = (d1M + 12 * d1Y) - (d2M + 12 * d2Y);
    if (diffInMonths <= 1) return "1 month";
    else if (diffInMonths < 12) return diffInMonths + " months";
    var diffInYears = Math.floor(diffInMonths / 12);
    if (diffInYears <= 1) return "1 year";
    else if (diffInYears < 12) return diffInYears + " years";
}
```

I tried making one for minutes:

```
var d1T = d1.getMinutes();
var d2T = parseInt(splitTime[1], 10);
var diffInMinutes = (d1T + 60 *d1H + 24 * d1D + 360 * d1M + 12 * d1Y) - (d2T + 60 *d2H + 24 * d2D + 360 * d2M + 12 * d2Y);

if (diffInHours <= 1) return diffInMinutes + " minutes";
```

However, when I add in the second group of code, the minutes are not displayed correctly. For example, a video that was uploaded 7 minutes ago will display as "947 minutes ago".

Comment: use a library like moment.js or timeago

Comment: But... how would a library like timeago be implemented into my script to connect with youtube to determine how long a video was uploaded ago? @ArunPJohny

Comment: Welcome to [so]. The phrase "doesn't work" can mean a whole lot of things, all different in their respects. It's often overused and doesn't add much to your question. Consider improving your post by describing the specific issue at hand, and how your code "doesn't work". Thank you!

Comment: It doesn't work... allow me to rephrase. When I add in the second group of code, the minutes that display are not right.. for example a video that was uploaded 7 minutes ago will display as "947 minutes ago" @Qantas94Heavy

Comment: @user2998050: thanks for that, that's much better.

Comment: likely simpler to work it using `getTime()` for both dates, do raw math on the difference without using `getMinutes()`

Answer (score 1):

Try [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) which saves all the work.

Comment: How do i use Moment.JS and implement it into my existing code to find the upload date from youtube

Comment: @user2998050 I don't know the format of your `timestamp`, but the format looks like `2013-02-08T09:30:26`. If so, moment.js can parse it directly. Just include it and call `moment(timestamp).fromNow()` and it will return strings like `2 hours ago`.

Answer (score 0):

for condition write :

```
if (diffInMinutes <= 60) return diffInMinutes + " minutes";
```

instead of

```
if (diffInHours <= 1) return diffInMinutes + " minutes";
```

If it also doesn't work use

```
var diff = endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime();
var hours = Math.floor(diff / 1000 / 60 / 60);
diff -= hours * 1000 * 60 * 60;
var minutes = Math.floor(diff / 1000 / 60);
```

Hope it will work.

Comment: by putting alerts can u tell me the values of d1T,d1H,d1D,d1M,d1Y,d2T,,d2H,d2D,d2M,d2Y

Comment: d1T = Minutes d1H = Hours d1D= Days d1M= Months d1Y= Years and the same for D2T... d2H...